# Can't add product to category, category missing - opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm using Opencart 2.0.1.1. I've added a new category with a filter, this is working great.
Now I want to add a product to that category, I've added the product, but in the Links tab I can't assign the product to the right category, because it is missing.

[image: links tab]

The newly created category is not showing. What could be the problem? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drop down list you see in the *category* field under *links* tab is only a helper list. It shows the first 5 alphabetically.

Type the first few letters of your category name and it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

In the case Links tab not appear , the please check newly installed extention,

In my case after disable the Admin Product Minified extension, Links tab works and I could update the category. Hope this help.